LLDB does not refresh the current debugging source file when it step into a branch included from another assembly file
I am trying to debug an assembly program in Apple ARM64 but once I break the project into multiple files the debugger won't work properly. LLDB debugger won't refresh the current debugging source file on stepping into a branch included from another assembly file.
Once it step into that "external" branch, I can see it points to the correct line number as it step over the instructions, but it still using the main source file instead of showing the source file for that branch.
Here is a minimal example of how I am doing it:
example.s
.align 4
.global _start

_start:
    mov X0, #0 // exit code
    b exit

.include "exit.s"

exit.s
.align 4

exit:
    mov X16, #1         // exit system call
    svc #0              // call system call

Building and debugging this program:
as example.s -g -o example.o
ld example.o -o example -l System -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e _start -arch arm64

μ arm64-assembly/example main●  lldb example
(lldb) target create "example"
Current executable set to '/example' (arm64).
(lldb) b start
Breakpoint 1: where = example`start + 4, address = 0x0000000100003f94
(lldb) run
Process 61477 launched: '/example' (arm64)
Process 61477 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003f94 example`start at example.s:6
   3
   4    _start:
   5            mov X0, #0 // exit code
-> 6            b exit
   7
   8    .include "exit.s"
   9
Target 0: (example) stopped.
warning: This version of LLDB has no plugin for the language "assembler". Inspection of frame variables will be limited.
(lldb) stepi
Process 61477 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = instruction step into
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003fa0 example`exit at example.s:4
   1    .align 4
   2    .global _start
   3
-> 4    _start:
   5            mov X0, #0 // exit code
   6            b exit
   7
Target 0: (example) stopped.

As we can see, it points to line 4, which is correct, but it still showing by mistake the example.s source file instead exit.s content.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

While that does sound like a bug (or a limitation of debug info) I recommend you don't use .include and instead just link object files together. Then it should work.

I suspect that lldb thinks that .include is for macros, and not for actual code.  I'm with @Jester, just link the two together.

This sort of error is usually a problem with the line tables emitted by the compiler.  When I run the lldb command image dump line-table example.s on your example, the first line of the include is given an erroneous line number: /tmp/example.s:134217725.  Your version of clang seems differently buggy here.  Anyway, probably best to file a bug with the clang issues tracker: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues

Note, the debug format "DWARF"'s line tables are designed to handle inclusions and that all works correctly in the C front end.  So this isn't a limitation of DWARF, more likely a bug in the assembly front-end when emitting the line tables over an inclusion.

And to be clear, lldb never makes inferences based on things like the ".include" in a source file.   In general debuggers don't do much with source code beyond displaying it.  Instead they get source location tracking info from the line tables emitted by the compiler, since that's who actually knows how to parse these things.

Since, as mentioned, it seems to be a bug in the assembler tool. I was wondering if could make it work with a newer version of as (Mac OS X Mach-O GNU-based assemblers), but I couldn't find a way to update it, beside depending on Xcode releases. I even installed llvm v17 and v19 and tried to compile it using clang and gcc with -c argument. But it somehow broke the debugger even more. Therefore, I gave up using .include directive and followed your suggestions on linking the objects together instead. The debugger is working as expected now.
